# How to create partial index on couchbase using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, couchbase

I need to configure the code to create partial index from c# code, i found the `bucketmanager` for creation of indexes. But i am not able to find the solution for partial index.
Here is the link for bucket manager .net sdk.
[BucketManager](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-net-client-2.2.7/html/93FF0208.htm)

Code:

```
public IResult CreateIndex(
    string indexName,
    bool defer = false,
    params string[] fields
)
```

I can create partial index using N1QL on couchbase query tool, but i need to create partial index from c#.
Here is the link for Index document.
[indexes in couchbase](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/services-and-indexes/indexes/indexing-and-query-perf.html)

Query:

```
CREATE INDEX travel_info ON `travel-sample`(name, id, icoo, iata)
WHERE type='airline';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/couchbase/gocb#QueryIndexManager

Comment: old but should work https://docs.couchbase.com/go-sdk/1.6/start-using-sdk.html

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the index definition as a query:

```
var request = new QueryRequest("CREATE INDEX travel_info ON `travel-sample`(name, id, icoo, iata) WHERE type = 'airline';");

var queryResult = _bucket.Query<dynamic>(request);
```

That should work.